# Convert data frame to gtsummary object in ordert to format table

Tags: r, dplyr, gtsummary

I create a table using tbl_summary and would like to convert it back to a data frame in order to mutate columns. Next, I would like to convert the data frame back to a gtsummary object for additional formatting. Is this possible?

Note that the real world example involves looping through hundreds of tables (with multiple variables), and that the main reason for converting to a dataframe is to remove low n cells.

Data Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

df <- data.frame(a= c("m","f","f","m", "m", "f", "f"),b= c("g1","g2","g1","g2", "g2", "g2", "g2"))

> df
  a  b
1 m g1
2 f g2
3 f g1
4 m g2
5 m g2
6 f g2
7 f g2
```

Table with column change:

```
tbl_summary_object <- df %>%
  tbl_summary(
    missing="no",
    by=a,
    label=list(
      b ~ "group"
    ),
    percent="row"
  )

# remove n<2
convert <- 
tbl_summary_object[[1]] %>% 
     dplyr::mutate(across(c(stat_1, stat_2), 
                          ~case_when(as.numeric(gsub(",", "", sub("*\\(.*", "", .)))  <2  ~ "low n", TRUE ~ as.character(.))))

# convert last object to gtsummary object?
```

Comment: I guess you need to assign it back to `tbl_summary_object[[1]] <-`

Comment: Check out the `gtsummary::modify_table_body()` function. You can directly modify the underlying tibble of the gtsummary object without losing the gtsummary class. You cannot convert a tibble directly to gtsummary

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg This would work well. Is this error expected? Error: 'modify_table_body' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gtsummary

Comment: Here's the help file https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify_table_body.html

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeing that message